# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class

Tags: 8

I am trying to convert a module from D7 to D8. I had parts of it working earlier but after some code edits i now get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Drupal\delete_fields\DeleteFields in E:\www\drupal8\sites\all\modules\delete_fields\src\Form\DeleteFields.php on line 128
```

when i try to do a cache clear.

128 is the last line of the file and i have searched entire project and the only place DeleteFields shows up is in my module's class file:

```
namespace Drupal\delete_fields;

/**
 * Defines a class to build a listing of fields.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\field\Entity\Field
 * @see field_ui_entity_info()
 */
class DeleteFields extends ConfigEntityListBuilder
{
```

My guess is the class is getting cached somewhere and there is a bug in Drupal which is not letting this get cleared.

I tried drush rr but it seems like this is no longer available (i get command not found); even though it is listed in drush docs.

Answer (score 1):

Given your question's source code and namespace, the class code you pasted is located in `delete_fields/src/DeleteFields.php`.

When you compare this with the error message, you will find that you have another `DeleteFields` class in `delete_fields/src/Form`.

Despite the possible different sub-namespaces, this doesn't work in Drupal, as it autoloads all classes of enabled modules into the `\Drupal` namespace and having two loaded classes with the same name within a namespace is not possible in PHP. Therefore your class names should be unique.

Rename your form class to `DeleteFieldsForm` or `DeleteFieldsSettingsForm`, or whatever name describes its purpose and reason for existence best.

Comment: It's not exact that it doesn't work in Drupal: It doesn't work in PHP. In all the files that PHP loads, there cannot be two classes with the same name. There is a work-around to that, but it cannot be used in all the cases.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Ok, maybe not expressed well enough. I edited my answer to reflect your concerns. But: Same names are possible. Just not within the same namespace. ;)

Comment: I didn't mean it was wrong. I only wanted to be sure users who read this don't think Drupal is a special case for handling PHP classes/interfaces.

Comment: No, the only file that existed when this error occurred was in delete_fields/src/Form. I uninstalled the module and reinstalled and the issue resolved itself. Hence the bottom part of my question - this doesn't have to do with my code it has to do with how Drupal caches classes and doesn't properly clean them up. I am not sure if there is a drush command to clean this up. Drush docs stats thee is a RR command but i have also seen this has been replaced with CR (which did not fix the issue).

Comment: Ok, glad you found the cache-rebuild command for Drush. So additionally keep the above advice in mind. This is why it is best practice also to let your form class names end on `Form`. And if you state that it was the only class present at that time, check your namespace. For your forms it should be `Drupal\delete_fields\Forms`. The `Drupal\delete_fields` namespace applies to custom classes placed within your `delete_fields/src` folder only.

Comment: Correction: The namespace must be `Drupal\delete_fields\Form`. Had an `s` too much in my above comment. (Still early here.)